# Adapted but not progressively measurable?

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request

Let $X(t,\omega)$ be a stochastic process:

$$
X: \mathbb{R}^+ \times \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R},
$$

where $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}_t, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$ is a stochastic basis.

Some definitions:

- $X$ is said to be *measurable* if it is Borel measurable with respect to the product $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^+) \otimes \mathcal{F}$, where $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^+)$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}^+$.
- $X$ is said to be *adapted* if, for all $t>0$, $X(t, \omega)$ is $\mathcal{F}_t$-measurable.
- $X$ is said to be *progressively measurable* if, for all $T > 0$, the restriction of 
  $X$ to $[0, T] \times \Omega$ is Borel measurable with respect to the product $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}([0, T]) \otimes \mathcal{F}_T$-measurable.

> **Question**
>
> Apparently an adapted and measurable process need not be progressively measurable. This necessarily means that $\mathcal{B}([0, T]) \otimes \mathcal{F}_t$ 
>   is not the $\sigma$-algebra $[0, T] \times \Omega$ inherits as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^+ \times \Omega$. Could somebody give a simple example of such a process, adapted and measurable but not progressively measurable? Or a reference for such?

Comment: A general reference with some details on such matters would be great.

Comment: An excellent answer is found [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/176622/progressively-measurable-vs-adapted). Personally, I really like _Theory of Stochastic Processes_ by Gusak et al. (Springer, 2010), it is however a problem book, so it may not qualify as a reference. It also contains an example (Ex. 3.7, Solution on p. 31) of a measurable, adapted process which is not progressively measurable.

Comment: @binkyhorse I don't get it. The given counterexample (i.e. deterministic non-Borel measurable) is not measurable in the sense stated in this question, i.e. it is not measurable with respect to $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^+) \otimes \mathcal{F}$ - or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: @saz I was too quick there, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Michael have you found an example of measurable, adapted but not progressively measurable process?

Comment: @ConradoCosta Yeah, but it's been a while. I can try digging it up and post it. Do you happen to have one to post too?

Comment: I would appreciate it very much. So far I think that every measurable adapted function is progressively measurable. I will be glad to see a counter example

Comment: @ConradoCosta Where can I see the example which you mentioned above? Can you share it?